# Passing and Calling a Function outside the same file

Tags: flutter, dart

in this file, I have the function `setFilters` but I need to use this function inside FilterScreen(another stateful widget), So I passed it into the route  `FiltersScreen(setFilters)`

here is main.dart:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Map<String, bool> _filters = {
    'gluten': false,
    'lactose': false,
    'vegan': false,
    'vegetarian': false,
  };

  void setFilters(Map<String, bool> _filterData) {
    setState(() {
      _filters = _filterData;
    });
      }
.

.
.
.
.
routes: {
        TabsScreen.routeName: (context) => TabsScreen(),
        CategoryMealScreen.routeName: (context) => CategoryMealScreen(),
        MealDetailsScreen.routeName: (context) => MealDetailsScreen(),
        FiltersScreen.routeName: (context) => FiltersScreen(setFilters),
      },
```

here is the second file.
I received the function as `x` and I need to call it in the IconButton. I tried `Widget.x` but did not work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../wedgits/main_drawer.dart';

class FiltersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = "filters";

  final Function x;

  FiltersScreen(this.x);

  @override
  _FiltersScreenState createState() => _FiltersScreenState();
}

class _FiltersScreenState extends State<FiltersScreen> {
  bool _glutenFree = false;
  bool _lactoseFree = false;
  bool _viegan = false;
  bool _vegetarian = false;

  Widget buildSwitchListTile(
    String title,
    String subtitle,
    bool currentvalue,
    Function updateValue,
  ) {
    return SwitchListTile(
        title: Text(title),
        subtitle: Text(subtitle),
        value: currentvalue,
        onChanged: updateValue);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Your Filters"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.save),
              onPressed: () {} // here I want to call the function x
              ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: You can try calling widget.x()

Comment: I tried it did not work

Comment: "Did not work" does not help diagnose the problem.  What happens?  Note that since `widget.x` would be calling `setFilters`, and because `setFilters` takes a `Map<String, bool>` argument, you would need to supply one. (You also should declare `FiltersScreen.x` as `void Function(Map<String, bool>) x` so type errors can be caught by the analyzer.)

Comment: Thanks, jamesdlin, the problem was too silly I do not know how I missed it. I wrote `Widget.x`      the correct is `widget.x`   with a small letter

Comment: @DevonRay you were right. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use onPressed like this:

```
onPressed: () => widget.x()
```

Comment: Ohhh! I figured it out after an hour of trying I wrote it with a capital letter  `widget` is the correct, not `Widget`   also it worked without the prentheses like   `onPressed: () => widget.x`

Comment: Great! Kindly accept it as a correct answer.